# Why does my c code skip the printf line and goes straight to gets(array)

Tags: arrays, c, printf, scanf, gets

I am unsure why my code is skipping the `printf` after `scanf`. Only after I input my `gets(array)` does my `printf` print the statement.

```c
void stack_(void) {
  int amount;
  printf("PLease enter amount\t");
  scanf("%i ", &amount);
  char array[amount];
  printf("user amount is %i\n", amount);
  gets(array);
  puts(array);
}
```

Comment: Please 1. format your code properly 2. copy-paste as text the interactive session from your terminal/console/whatever showing what is your input and how it is interleaved with the output.

Comment: [never use gets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/6699433)

Comment: you have to use gets if you want to add blank space to your arrays

Comment: @LePiff That proves that you did not read the link about why you should never use gets

Comment: But you could add a `fflush(stdout);` after the `printf`

Comment: who said that `gets()` is used to add blank space to arrays?

Comment: `gets` is catching the newline left in the input stream from the `scanf` call for `amount`; you'll need some way to remove it before the `gets` call (usually something like `while (getchar() != '\n') /* empty loop */ ;`).  But like klutt says, never use `gets` - use `fgets` instead.

Comment: Would you say to use gets only when using Malloc due to the fact that i won't need to predefine my array size? since using fgets, I will need to specify the amount i wish to input....

Comment: @LePiff: ***NEVER*** use `gets`.  It was removed from the standard library in the 2011 revision of the standard.  It *will* (not might, but *will*) introduce a point of failure in your code.  Yes, you need to specify the maximum number of characters to read with `fgets`, meaning you need to know how large your input buffer is.  C doesn't automatically extend storage for you as you write to it (which is part of *why* `gets` was so dangerous), you have to manage all that yourself.

Answer (score 0):

`%d` , not `%i` .  And you have a waste space in `scanf`

Comment: It looks like the suggested edit gets the `%d` and `%i` the wrong way round. However it does present the information a bit better. Perhaps you should do something similar rather than rolling back and making snarky comments

Comment: @DavidW really?

Comment: What does "//////////////" mean? That's what they're trying to clear up. I agree they've changed the meaning of the answer though and you shouldn't accept that

Comment: [`%d` is the same as `%i`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)

Comment: @phuclv d is base10. But now i spot this `char array[amount];` haha

Comment: `%d` is exactly the same as `%i` for `printf`. It's a little bit different for `scanf` but it's not the problem here. Neither is `char array[amount];` because VLA is valid in C99

Comment: @phuclv but it's not C from 1999. it's not valid in say C17. so we have some unknown compiler

Comment: looks like  `gcc` works with it without tuning.

Comment: even `gcc -std=c17 -pedantic-errors ...` goes. Didn't know

Comment: The compiler i am using is GNU GCC Compiler.  How is %d and %i differs when using Scanf?

Comment: autodetection on `%i`